# Crumbs module won't display correct current page. Displays 'Anchor'

Tags: breadcrumbs, taxonomy-terms

I am using the crumbs module to create a breadcrumb for my website. I have the **'Show the current page at the end of the breadcrumb trail.'** setting enabled however on one of my pages the current page is getting replaced with the word **'Anchor'**, instead of of **Home>Products>'Lambswool Dusters'**

Does anyone know where this is coming from? The name of the page is correct and all of my other breadcrumbs are being generated properly.

I might also add I am generating the urls using taxonomy terms and I do have page anchors on the page.

Output I am getting.
[image: Image of what I am getting]

Comment: Funny. What version of Crumbs, and what theme are you using? Sometimes the theme can mess with the breadcrumb generated by Crumbs.

Comment: Also can you use the Admin > Structure > Crumbs > Debug page to get more info?

Comment: @donquixote I am using 7.x-2.0-alpha3. It also occurs in the stable version of crumbs. I am using omega base theme that I have sub-themed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue after using the crumbs debug tool. I had stupidly named a link **'Anchor'** when I was creating a menu and forgotten about this. This menu item was overriding the output I was looking for.

Here is my debug results if it helps anyone. Thanks to **donquixote** for pointing me in the right direction to use the debug tool.

[image: Debug results for reference]